# Using RewriteRules in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

Everytime someone visits www.cars.com/parts I want them to be redirected to www.planes.com. After that the paths are the same. For example www.cars.com/parts/engine should go to www.planes.com/engine and www.cars.com/parts/wheels should go to www.planes.com/wheels and so forth. As of right now I have the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 ServerName www.cars.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.cars.com/parts$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ www.planes.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, the problem is that www.cars.com/parts is taking me to www.planes.com/parts and not www.planes.com.
Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the RewriteRule to :

```
 RewriteRule ^/parts(.*)$ www.planes.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

The $1 is substituted with the pattern detected in the parenthesis. So now it should append everything after /parts.

Comment: It looks like it is now appending everything after /parts. Thanks. The only problem I have now is that when I go to www.cars.com it takes me to planes.com. Is there a way to get it so if I go to www.cars.com it still takes me to the homepage of cars.com instead of the homepage of planes.com.

Comment: Try  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cars\.com/parts$ [NC]

Comment: What exactly does the backslash do? It is still taking me to the wrong homepage. Do I have to include another RewriteRule that will ignore  any rewrite rule if I access the homepage of cars directly?

Comment: In regular expressions dot(.) means match any character. With the backslash you are instructing the parser to treat it as the character dot. The HTTP_HOST doesn't contain the full URI so try REQUEST_URI variable instead: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/parts(.*)$ [NC]